# Filter elements in expandable list jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this situation:

[image]

In my input text i have set a filter function, but this is not what i want to show. I would like to hide all divs (or a links) with class .filter that do not contain the input string (in this case  i would have only element "A"). 
How can i get that?
This is my filter function right now:

```
    function filter(element) {
        var value = $(element).val();
        $("#theList > div").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
    });
}
```

HTML code here: https://jsfiddle.net/0asx3nhL/26/

Comment: might be good if you show us the HTML so we can check if what you're doing makes sense in terms of the structure. This phrase is not right: "all divs with id #element". In a HTML document, IDs must be unique. Any duplicate IDs are considered invalid elements. You could give the same class to multiple elements though.

Comment: @ADyson added html. You're right about div ids, i will fix it now so you can consider classes (hide all divs with some class)

Comment: You have multiple of the same IDs from looking at your JSFiddle, as @ADyson said, after the first ID, the rest of the ones that are the same become invalid

Comment: This is how you make the function work https://jsfiddle.net/0asx3nhL/3/ - But I don't have enough time to fix the filtering logic itself so I'm posting it as a comment

Comment: the jquery functions didn't work in the fiddle because you didn't include jquery in the fiddle...it's not loaded by default!

Comment: @ADyson jQuery is loaded, not working anyway.

Comment: @Leo repeated ids removed.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that the filter function isn't actually being run.

The second is that you're targeting the wrong element when looking for the text. You're looking at the divs, but the text to be filtered is within an anchor (`<a>`) element inside that div.

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0asx3nhL/30/

The key elements of code are as follows:

1) Changing the "filter" function to be an event handler listening for changes to the search box. I've used the keyup event so it changes as you type.

2) Changing the selector of the "each" loop so that it targets the anchors, which are identified using a particular class - "list-group-item".

```
$(function() {
  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.glyphicon', this)
    .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
    .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });

  $("#filtra").change(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#theList .list-group-item").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you should bind it to `input` event, and not `change` so that the filter will apply as you type

Comment: please define "not working". It works for me. I type "A" and only the A option remains. I type "B", same thing, only B remains. I clear the field, everything is shown again. https://jsfiddle.net/0asx3nhL/29/

Comment: Ok, it's working but that's not the result i wanted. I already got that way. My problem is that if I type "A" i would like to have only "A" option remaining, while others hided, "First" "Second" and "Third" too. Is that possible?

Comment: definitely. since they have a class in common - "list-group-item" it's actually very simple. Just change `$("#theList .filter").each(function() {` to `$("#theList .list-group-item").each(function() {` . I have edited the answer to reflect this, and updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0asx3nhL/30/